# Load testing ZeroMQ (ZMQ_STREAM) for finding the maximum simultaneous users it can handle

Tags: zeromq, load-testing, web-architecture

Does anyone have any real-world scenarios that load-tested ZMQ sockets for maximum no. of 'concurrent users' (not throughput) they can handle? Looks like ZeroMQ has some serious problems with FD limits.

The scenario is: there are numerous web-server frameworks out there that are boasting of millions of concurrent users they can handle - now if ZeroMQ cannot handle beyond FD_SETSIZE no. of users at any point of time, it is a very serious restriction on scalability (since FDs are not just process resources, but also machine resources, so no point in spawning a new process in the same machine).

To verify, I am trying to load test ZMQ_STREAM to find how many concurrent users it can sustain. Its a simple "hello-world" response server that just listens on ZMQ_STREAM and returns "hello world" for every request (in a strict receive followed by send style).

Now, while testing with JMeter (using users=1000), hit the assertion: `zmq_assert (fds.size () <= FD_SETSIZE)`. What does this signify? That ZMQ is holding FD_SETSIZE number of FDs? But (as per the below code) each connection is opened and closed immediately, I do not see how is it possible that more than few FDs could be simultaneously open at any point of time.

> Question: If this is the case, what is the way for any ZMQ based app
>   to achieve million-user concurrent connections? (apart from the
>   obvious and meaningless solution of having 1000 machines each handling
>   1000 users, or increasing the FD_SETSIZE to be an insanely large number)

Anyone knows anything about how and why these FDs are used and how they get exhausted (and more importantly how other frameworks such as, nginx node.js do not have this problem) please throw some light.

The server code, if it matters is below:

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(void)
{
    void *ctx = zmq_ctx_new();

    void *socket = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_STREAM);
    int rc = zmq_bind(socket, "tcp://*:8080");
    uint8_t id[256];
    size_t id_size = 256;
    char msg[4096];
    size_t msg_size = 4096;
    int nCount = 0;
    char http_response[] =
        "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "Hello, World!";
    int nResponseLen = strlen(http_response);
    while (1) {
        id_size = zmq_recv(socket, id, 256, 0);
        msg_size = zmq_recv(socket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
        msg[msg_size] = '\0';
        std::cout << ++nCount << " -----\n";

        zmq_send(socket, id, id_size, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
        zmq_send(socket, http_response, nResponseLen, ZMQ_SNDMORE);

        zmq_send(socket, id, id_size, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
        zmq_send(socket, 0, 0, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
    }
    zmq_close(socket);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

Using JMeter, users=1000

Comment: What's your OS? https://zeromq.jira.com/browse/LIBZMQ-57

Comment: OS is windows. Yes, aware of the possibility to increase the FD_SETSIZE as a work around. But more interested in finding out what is the right way of achieving the maximum no. of concurrent connections (with ZMQ and if possible how other frameworks have avoided this problem). If each connected client of ZMQ socket demands a new FD, then we are back in the game of good old 'one thread per client' style of resource-hungry server problems (slashdot, c10k etc..). FD may be cheaper than thread, but still scalability bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean when you say "each connection is opened and closed immediately"?  You bind on a `stream` socket, which accepts incoming requests in the `while` loop, which runs perpetually and never closes anything.  The call to `zmq_close(socket);` after the loop is never reached.

Even the last part of the message explicitly uses `ZMQ_SNDMORE`, which should keep the connection open waiting for more text.  Presumably to allow a small number of clients a lower overhead for repeated connections, I guess.  It should probably be:

```
zmq_send(socket, 0, 0, 0);
```

I don't know which of these issues would release the resources to allow a larger number of clients, if either, but probably it's an abuse of ZMQ (or at least misguided) to try and write an HTTP server in it or try to make it scale to millions of concurrent peers/clients.

node.js and nginx are event based concurrent I/O systems, they are significantly different architecturally from ZMQ, and they are made to solve different problems.  Trying to make ZMQ into them is going about things the wrong way.  What you probably want is to use node.js with socket.io, or if you're using it for HTTP then just use it's native `http` module.

Comment: You are right about ZMQ not being the right thing for these kind of things - but recently there were few claims on ZMQ_ROUTER_RAW and ZMQ_STREAM sockets to the contrary. Hence doing a load test to see if they are really capable of doing some serious work - but till now couldn't find any evidence. As for the connections and the ZMQ_SNDMORE, for some reason that's how the examples mandate them (with some cautions about not following them leading to weird results). Anyway, the goal was to confirm that ZMQ has these serious resource limitations. Seems ZMQ has long way to go further.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense, though I would hesitate to qualify only the kind of work being done here as "serious work"... it's well established that ZMQ can handle a high message load with a reasonable number of peers/clients very well.  Would you mind posting a link to the claims that ZMQ is suitable to the types of workloads you're aiming for here?

Comment: By the way in [Pieter Hintjen's blog entry](http://hintjens.com/blog:42) where he wrote the code this appears to be based on (and I see your comment at the bottom), he definitely closes the `send` with `0` instead of `ZMQ_SNDMORE`.  I suppose there could be a problem with the C++ binding (though that hardly seems likely).  In any event, try it with that fix and see if you get different results.

Comment: Also, [about a year ago in this zmq mailing list post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.zeromq.devel/19524) Hintjen states that he's "impressed" that the guy reached 100k connections, implying it might not be easy to do so.

Comment: +1 Thanks Jason. Makes sense. About using 0, indeed that was my first attempt - it was not any better either. Here is related q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305254/client-maintenance-in-zmq-router?lq=1

Comment: A bit late to the party, but sending an empty message frame to a peer will close that connection (at least in 4.1) see the notes on ZMQ_STREAM in http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-socket